# want to change columntype in a table through migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i have a table in which there are two columns from and to of type datatime i want to change the datatype from datetime to date. i dont know the exact command for chagning column type in migrations like rails g

Comment: Ever tried the docs? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the command line, run:

`rails generate migration change_data_type_for_table_column`

Write your migration as:

```
change_table :table do |t|  
  t.change :column, :type 
end
```

Comment: This method is especially helpful if you have multiple columns you need to change. If you are just doing a one-off, you can simply: `change_column :table_name, :column_name, :new_type`

Answer (score 2):

Use [change_column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).

```
change_column(:table, :column, :date)
```